# Widen geocoding results (all political loations returned)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, geocode

I am trying to widen the search results returned by geocoding. I'm essentially createing a jquery ui autocomplete input like this http://tech.cibul.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/geocode/index.html (tutorial here http://tech.cibul.org/geocode-with-google-maps-api-v3/).

For example if I enter 'waterloo' in the location bar I get 1 option: **Waterloo, ON, Canada**.

What about all of the other Waterloos? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterloo

This is the crux of the code:

```
$('input[name="location"]').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
            response($.map(results, function(item) {
                return {
                    label: item.formatted_address,
                    value: item.formatted_address,
                    latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                    longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                }
            }));
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, it is impossible to get the Geocoding API to make a sane list of location suggestions even with V3 and region biasing (related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866102/google-maps-geocoding-api-country-biasing-bizarre-results)).

What you get through the API varies greatly from what you get when entering an ambiguous name in the Maps application. I am not aware of any workaround.

I've reached the conclusion that if you want to offer a list of place names, you need some other data source, for example [Wikipedia's list of cities.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_cities)

Comment: Yes I guess I'll have to look at another route. The wikipedia idea is good except I don't want to narrow the list down, on bias the returned order to show UK, US results first. For example I'd still like a user to be able to choose a town in whether it be in Congo, China, US, Venezuela, UK or Germany. Damn, I wouldn't have imagined this would have been so hard.

Comment: @Colin I know, it stinks. Google have all the data, they should be able to provide a list of cities no problem... But for some reason, they won't. If you find a solution for this within the Maps API, I'd appreciate a ping, I've settled for a compromise at the moment. But as far as I can see, there is no way.

Comment: check out my update on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555307/smart-location-form-field - I've worked something up here http://jsfiddle.net/ekzMN/95/ and combine this with Google Geocoder as a secondary source to provide samrter results. It needs a bit of work though. Let me know if you come up with any improvements. I've marked this as correct as it's impossible using Google Geocoder alone.

Comment: @Colin very interesting, thanks for the link! I will check it out.

Comment: also check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714477/global-location-input-autocomplete I created a jquery plugin.